# Polling data from mongodb 4.4.0 connector in mule 3.9

Tags: java, mongodb, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

unable to poll data from mongodb 4.4.0 connector in anypoint studio mule 3.9

I have a collections in mongodb with about 1000 records been added daily, I was trying to get all individual records and using cron scheduler or fixed frequency scheduler in anypoint to fetch those records per hour. Apparently mongodb couldn't fetch records

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd">
    <flow name="_mlFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="20" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
            <mongo:find-documents config-ref="Mongo_DB" collection="actions" limit="20" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
        </poll>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: can you post more info on what is not working? the error message etc.

Comment: Failed to transform from "java.lang.String" to "org.bson.Document" readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is END_OF_DOCUMENT

Answer (score 0):

When capturing the result set a transformation is necessary.

```
<flow name="_mlFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="20" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
        <mongo:find-documents config-ref="Mongo_DB" collection="actions" limit="20" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
    </poll>
  <dw:transform-message doc:name="prepForMongo">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
             %output application/json
              ---
              payload]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the poll scope and use mongo DB connector only.That should eliminate the error.